# Show something in active mode line instead of all mode lines

Tags: mode-line

I set up an org-timer indicator in the mode line with this.

```lisp
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 (quote
  (
   ;; org-timer
   (:eval
    (unless (not org-timer-countdown-timer)
      (propertize (let* ((rtime (decode-time
                                 (time-subtract
                                  (timer--time org-timer-countdown-timer)
                                  (current-time))))
                         (rmins (nth 1 rtime))
                         (rsecs (nth 0 rtime)))
                    (format " %d:%d" rmins rsecs))
                  'face '(:foreground "cyan" :weight bold)
                  'help-echo "org-timer")))

   )))
```

I want this org-timer indicator to be shown in the **active mode line** only, instead of all mode lines. How to do it?

Comment: See:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22682/2287

Comment: @lawlist Can't understand your code. Don't know how to apply on my case.

Comment: The `redisplay` engine is able to check each window under certain circumstances (e.g., when the mode-line is refreshed naturally, or when it is forced to refresh).  When the `mode-line-format` contains the function `(selected-window)`, a different window will be returned as redisplay visits the various windows.  That value can be compared with a pre-recorded value -- e.g., the `post-command-hook` can be used to record the last known `selected-window` and that value can later be compared with a function inside the `mode-line-format`.  So, I use the PCH to record/store the `selected-window`.

Comment: @lawlist I have checked out your code, but have not found general usage for my case. If I change to other thing instead of `org-timer`. What should I do? I hope a more general way. Even it did inspired me. Can you give me more exactly code example? Because I found it set different `'face`, But I need to change the display string.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but this question looks similar to this one: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13842/115

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following example, the word “ACTIVE” will appear in the mode-line of the window that is active, and all other windows will display the word “INACTIVE” in the mode-line.

Be sure to try this example with `emacs -Q` to verify that it works as advertised.  Thereafter, customize it as needed.

Add additional hooks as needed to call `ml-update-all`.

```lisp
(defvar ml-selected-window nil)

(defun ml-record-selected-window ()
  (setq ml-selected-window (selected-window)))

(defun ml-update-all ()
  (force-mode-line-update t))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'ml-record-selected-window)

(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'ml-update-all)

(setq-default mode-line-format
  '(:eval
      (if (eq ml-selected-window (selected-window))
        "ACTIVE"
        "INACTIVE")))
```